# Improve script to get previous week day

Tags: powershell

I've got a little powershell script here that finds the last previous day.
At the moment I'm doing - If it's monday then subtract 3 days, if it's Sunday subtract 2 days and if it's any other day subtract 1.  This seems a bit dumb...  Is there a better way to do this?

```
$prevWD =
if ((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -eq 1) #Monday
{ (get-date).AddDays(-3) }
elseif ((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -eq 0) #Sunday
{ (get-date).AddDays(-2) }
ELSE { (get-date).AddDays(-1) } #Any other day
```

Comment: What's *last previous day*? The last working week day? So that sat/sun/mon -> previous friday, all other days point to the day before?

Comment: If this is your only logic there isnt that much of a pattern here that we could improve on. The only thing I would suggest is to use a `switch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the previous workday like this:

```psh
$d = Get-Date

$offset = ($d.DayOfWeek.value__ + 5) % 7
$delta1 = [math]::Floor([int]$offset / [int]5)
$delta2 = [math]::Floor([int]$offset / [int]6)

$prevWD = $d.AddDays(-($delta1 + $delta2 + 1)).DayOfWeek
```

However, it might be simpler to just do something like this:

```psh
$d = Get-Date

if ('Sunday','Monday' -contains $d.DayOfWeek) {
  $prevWD = 'Friday'
} else {
  $prevWD = $d.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek
}
```

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $now = Get-Date
PS C:\> 0..6 | % {
>>   $wd = $now.AddDays($_)
>>   $wd | % {
>>     $offset = ($_.DayOfWeek.value__ + 5) % 7
>>     $d1 = [math]::Floor([int]$offset / [int]5)
>>     $d2 = [math]::Floor([int]$offset / [int]6)
>>     "{0,-10}`t{1}" -f $wd.DayOfWeek, $_.AddDays(-($d1 + $d2 + 1)).DayOfWeek
>>   }
>> }
>>
Monday          Friday
Tuesday         Monday
Wednesday       Tuesday
Thursday        Wednesday
Friday          Thursday
Saturday        Friday
Sunday          Friday
```