# How to count X working days back in powershell?

Tags: powershell, counting

I'm trying to create a powershell script that would count X working days back in time from current date? The script should ask how many working days back to count and the output would be some kind of date back in time.

Example: I want to know how many calendar days I need to go back in time to get 20 working days. So I would enter number 20 and the output would be 12/31/2014. So in order to get 20 working days I need to start counting from Dec.31.2014 (There is one day of holidays (01/01/2015) between today and Dec.31.)

Working days are Mondays-Fridays except US statutory holidays.

I've found a lot of similar solutions to count number of days between two days:

- [Finding Dates Between Two Dates](https://web.archive.org/web/20160711153831/http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2014/07/07/finding-dates-between-two-dates.aspx)
- [Counting the Days with PowerShell](https://web.archive.org/web/20170613143655/http://www.integrationtrench.com/2014/05/counting-days-with-powershell.html)
- [Calculate Elapsed Business Hours Using PowerShell](https://pleasework.robbievance.net/howto-calculate-elapsed-business-hours-using-powershell/)

But none do exactly what I need.

This is the code I'm trying to modify...

```
$startdate = (Get-Date).date
$enddate = Get-Date -Date '2014-12-20'

$New_Years_Day2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-01-01'
$Martin_Luther_King2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-01-20'
$Washingtons_Birthday2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-02-17'
$Good_Friday2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-04-18'
$Memorial_Day2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-05-26'
$Independence_Day2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-07-04'
$Labor_Day2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-09-01'
$Thanksgiving_Day2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-11-27'
$Christmas2014 = Get-Date -Date '2014-12-25'
$New_Years_Day2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-01-01'
$Martin_Luther_King2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-01-19'
$Washingtons_Birthday2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-02-16'
$Good_Friday2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-04-03'
$Memorial_Day2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-05-25'
$Independence_Day2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-07-03'
$Labor_Day2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-09-07'
$Thanksgiving_Day2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-11-26'
$Christmas2015 = Get-Date -Date '2015-12-25'

 $difference = New-TimeSpan -Start $startdate -End $enddate
 "Days in all: " + $difference.Days

 $days = [Math]::Ceiling($difference.TotalDays)+1

 $workdays = 0..$days | ForEach-Object {
 $startdate
 $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
 } |
 Where-Object { $_.DayOfWeek -gt 0 -and $_.DayOfWeek -lt 6 -and  $startdate -ne $New_Years_Day2014 -and $startdate -ne $Martin_Luther_King2014 -and $startdate -ne $Washingtons_Birthday2014 -and $startdate -ne $Good_Friday2014 -and $startdate -ne $Memorial_Day2014 -and $startdate -ne $Independence_Day2014 -and $startdate -ne $Labor_Day2014 -and $startdate -ne $Thanksgiving_Day2014 -and $startdate -ne $Christmas2014 -and  $startdate -ne $New_Years_Day2015 -and $startdate -ne $Martin_Luther_King2015 -and $startdate -ne $Washingtons_Birthday2015 -and $startdate -ne $Good_Friday2015 -and $startdate -ne $Memorial_Day2015 -and $startdate -ne $Independence_Day2015 -and $startdate -ne $Labor_Day2015 -and $startdate -ne $Thanksgiving_Day2015 -and $startdate -ne $Christmas2015} |
 Measure-Object |
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

 "Workdays: $workdays"
```

Comment: This isn't a place to get "code [to] do exactly what [you] need". You've already found out how to count days in Powershell. We can't tell what a "working day" means to you, or which holidays you count. If there's a more specific coding question you have you should make that more clear before this question gets closed.

Comment: "But no code do exactly what I need." ... Then write some. Write down what working days are, create the logic on paper, write down what information you need to make your logic work, and start searching on how to get that so you could try to solve it. Then, if you get stuck on a specific problem, ask again. We're here to help you do it yourself, not to write it all for you.

Comment: Sorry. By working days I mean Monday-Friday, except US Statutory holidays.

Comment: That first link you give does exactly what you want, you just have to add a bit to filter out the holidays. Try and figure out how to do that and if you run into an error come back with the code you're working with. I managed to modify the code on that link to do what you want within a couple of minutes I'm sure you can at least come close if you really try.

Comment: OK. I will try my best, But like 3 days ago I even didn't know what powershell is. That is why I searched  the internet to find the  code closest to my needs. Could you recommend me any good powershell book with a lot of code examples, so I can start learning?

Comment: So I guss in  Where-Object { $_.DayOfWeek -gt 0 -and $_.DayOfWeek -lt 6}  line there should be listed all Statutory holidays and I should exclude those days by "-ne" (not equal) switch? Or mabye all statutory holidays can by stored  all together? like $Holidays ?

Comment: Looks like I'm not even close :-(. I don't know why "$startdate -ne $New_Years_Day2014"  doesn't compare different dates with all holidays.But anyways there must be more "intelligent" way  how to compare all holidays dates.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27484306/1630171) might give you some pointers.

Comment: OK this is just too much for me. I spent 5 hours trying to solve it without any success :-(

Comment: I retracted my close vote and upvoted this post. I'm sure people are already working on solutions to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will take two values. The first being the number of working days ago you are looking for a date match. The second, which is optional, will allow you to specify a start date. If omitted today's date is used.

```powershell
Function Get-WorkingDay{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
        [int]$maxWorkingDays,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
        [datetime]$startDate = (Get-Date).Date
    )

    $holidays = @(
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-01-01'),            # New_Years_Day2014
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-01-20'),            # Martin_Luther_King2014
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-02-17'),            # Washingtons_Birthday2014
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-04-18'),            # Good_Friday2014 
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-05-26'),            # Memorial_Day2014 
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-07-04'),            # Independence_Day2014
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-09-01'),            # Labor_Day2014
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-11-27'),            # Thanksgiving_Day2014
        (Get-Date -Date '2014-12-25'),            # Christmas2014
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-01-01'),            # New_Years_Day2015
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-01-19'),            # Martin_Luther_King2015
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-02-16'),            # Washingtons_Birthday2015 
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-04-03'),            # Good_Friday2015 
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-05-25'),            # Memorial_Day2015 
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-07-03'),            # Independence_Day2015
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-09-07'),            # Labor_Day2015 
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-11-26'),            # Thanksgiving_Day2015
        (Get-Date -Date '2015-12-25')             # Christmas2015
    )

    # Count down the working days checking each date as we progress
    $dateIndex = $startDate

    For($workingDayIndex = $maxWorkingDays; $workingDayIndex -gt 0; $workingDayIndex--){
        # Assume the current day is not a working day
        $isWorkingDay = $False

        Do{
            If (("Sunday","Saturday" -contains $dateIndex.DayOfWeek) -or ($holidays -contains $dateIndex)){
                # This is not a working day. Check the next day.
                # Write-Host "$($dateIndex.Date) is a weekend or holiday" -ForegroundColor Red
                $dateIndex = $dateIndex.AddDays(-1)
            } Else {
                # Current $dateIndex is a working day.
                $isWorkingDay = $True
            }
        } While(!$isWorkingDay)

        # Write-Host "Current Date: $($dateIndex.Date). Number of working days left: $workingDayIndex."

        # Set the $dateIndex to the previous day.
        $dateIndex = $dateIndex.AddDays(-1)
    }

    # The last date was the correct one. Re-add the day. 
    $dateIndex.AddDays(1)
}

Get-WorkingDay 10
```

We take your holiday dates and convert them into an array which will make the comparison much easier later on. This is a manual exercise so you need to be sure to update the dates regularly.

Using the variables `$maxWorkingDays` to determine how many working days back we need to go and `$workingDayIndex` to keep track of the progress. We use a `For` loop to count down the working days until we get to 1. While in the loop we check if the previous day was a working day. If not a smaller `Do..While` loop will set the date back until we reach a working day. I have placed some commented out `Write-Host` lines that can help explain where you are in the loop position.

`-contains` does the work for us since we are using arrays in the comparison and checking is one of the elements is in that aforementioned array. @AnsgarWiechers I swear I didn't steal the conditional logic from your linked post. I thought of it independently :)

**Sample Output** Today in this case is *Saturday, January 31, 2015 12:00:00 AM*

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> Get-WorkingDay 5

Monday, January 26, 2015 12:00:00 AM

PS C:\Users\Cameron> Get-WorkingDay 5 "02/01/2015"

Monday, January 26, 2015 12:00:00 AM
```

[image: Jan-Feb 2015]

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> Get-WorkingDay 5 "2014-11-27"

Thursday, November 20, 2014 12:00:00 AM
```

[image: November 2014 Calendar]

Comment: It looks like the code is not working properly if test is running on Saturdays or Sundays.or on Holidays. The number of working days shouldn't change on these days. It is quite easy to fix it for "Saturdays" or "Sundays".                                                                                        $a = (get-date).dayofweek
$startDate = (Get-Date).date

if ($a -eq "Saturday") {$startDate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1)}
if ($a -eq "Sunday") {$startDate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-2)}

Comment: But it is more complicated to fix the code when it is running on holidays, because holidays can be anytime between Monday and Friday. So $startDate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-X) is different for every holiday.

Comment: @wilo65 I dont understand what the issue is? It does count the working days back from dates does it not? Is it having issues when starting on weekends / holidays. Give me an example date that is not working and what you want to have as output. Oh... I see what the issue is. I will address that.

Comment: @wilo65 Am updating my answer. I saw the flaw that you were describing.

Comment: Actually it is still not working for holidays.  Get-WorkingDay 5 "2014-11-27"  (Thanksgiving) output is  "Friday November 21, 2014"       correct answer should be "Thursday November 20, 2014" Get-WorkingDay 5 "2014-05-26" (Memorial day) output is  "Tuesday May 20, 2014"   correct answer should be "Monday May 19, 2014"

Comment: Also one more question. Could your function has one more parameter for different countries? For example $holidaysUS = @( list of US holidays) $holidaysCanada = @( list of Canada holidays) .... That way I think it would be more universal.

Comment: It is working as I would have intended. If you want you could just change this line `$dateIndex.AddDays(1)` to `$dateIndex`. Does that work for you? As for your other question that is indeed possible. You just need to set up another parameter in the function. If you having issues with that please ask another question as that is out of scope for this one.

Comment: I don't think just changing $dateIndex.AddDays(1) to $dateIndex will fix the problem completely. With the change to $dateIndex output for Get-WorkingDay 5 "2014-11-20" (it is working day)  is "Thursday Nov. 13.2014" which is 6 days (including Nov 20).  Output for Get-WorkingDay 5 "2014-11-27" (Thanksgiving day) is "Thursday Nov 2014"  which is correct 5 days (current day "Thanksgiving day' doesn't count).  
Output for Get-WorkingDay 5 "2015-02-01" (it is working day)  is "Sunday Jan 25 2015" the correct answer should be "Tuesday Jan. 27.2015" (current day 2015-02-01 should count)

Comment: Yes, please I woluld like to count current day if it is a working day. It is quite easy to fix it for Saturdays and Sundays but it is tricky for holidays.For example if the script is running on Thanksgiving day (which is Thursday so the current day is not counted but. previous the day is Wednesday (which is working day), so Wednesday should be counted.But when the script is running on Memorial day(which is Monday May 26.2014), so (Monday, Sunday and Saturday) should not be counted.It looks to me quite complicated to fix it.

Comment: Alright I have looked at this for a long time and cannot find any issues. Granted that editting this line `$dateIndex.AddDays(1)` was a bad idea and it needs to be there as is. Your sample dates are confusing. Some of the days have the wrong days of the week associated. Please restart your PowerShell session and readd my code as it is in my current answer. Remove the quotes on my `Write-Host` lines so you can see what is happening. I am updating my answer with a highlighted calendar to show my logic works.

Comment: Yes you are right. I messed up those dates. I'm sorry about that. I can confirm your code is working correctly.Thank you for your help. Maybe tomorrow I will ask the question about setting up that extra parameter for different countries.

Comment: Here is a link to complementary question to this function.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269446/how-to-add-parameter-to-function-counting-working-days-in-powershell