# Powershell - Subtract two dates excluding the weekends

Tags: powershell

I have two dates:

1. `Current_Date`
2. `Last_Updated_Date`

I would like to take the `Current_Date` subtract the `Last_Updated_Date` without including the weekends.

This will be done in Powershell. Any input would be appreciated.

**Note**: This is different than the question [How to count X working days back in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28223261/) in that I would like to compare two dates, not go back X number of days.

Comment: Sounds like you are attempting to count the working days between two dates. This has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223261/how-to-count-x-working-days-back-in-powershell

Answer (score 1):

You may use a helper function for that:

```
function Get-WorkingDates {
   [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [datetime]$StartDate,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [datetime]$EndDate
    )
    # swap if the end date is before the start date
    if ($EndDate -lt $StartDate) { $StartDate, $EndDate = $EndDate, $StartDate }
    $difference = $enddate - $startdate  # or:  New-TimeSpan -Start $startdate -End $enddate
    $days = [Math]::Ceiling($difference.TotalDays) + 1
    # loop through the days and filter out the dates that are Saturday or Sunday
    1..$days | ForEach-Object {
        $startdate
        $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
    } | Where-Object { 1..5 -contains $_.DayOfWeek } 
    # or filter with    Where-Object { $_.DayOfWeek -gt 'Sunday' -and $_.DayOfWeek -lt 'Saturday' }
    # or something like Where-Object { $_.DayOfWeek -gt 0 -and $_.DayOfWeek -lt 6 }
}
```

and use it like this

```
Get-WorkingDates $Current_Date  $Last_Updated_Date
```

This will output an array of working day dates.
Of course you can capture that in a variable if you like:

```
$workingDates = Get-WorkingDates $Current_Date  $Last_Updated_Date
```

to get the number of working dates with `@($workingDates).Count`

<sup>the `@()` in the last example is to force the `$workingDates` variable to be an array that has a `.Count` property, even if there is only one date in it.</sup>

Comment: I have done the below, with a bit of change, instead of looking for past date, the below look for future date but the logic should be similar.