# Upload file from previous weekday to FTP using WinSCP

Tags: ftp, winscp, weekday

I transfer files (generated every weekday) to remote directory over FTP. I have set up a Windows scheduled task to automate transfer via **WinSCP** with a script which will be loaded as argument.

Filename format is `prefixYESTDATE.txt`

I am using `%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyymmdd%` to compose the filename which changes every weekday.

On Monday my logic of `-1D` in `TIMESTAMP` would fail (since it returns Sunday).

I am looking for a way to set the correct `YESTDATE` on Monday for the script.

Script:

```
open ftp://uname:pwd@ftp.abc.com/
cd destFolder
put prefix%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyymmdd%.txt
close
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct *"yesterday for Monday"* is *"Sunday"*.

[WinSCP `%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) cannot calculate weekdays.

---

You can use the following [PowerShell script with a use of WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell):

```powershell
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
$sessionOptions.HostName = "ftp.example.com"
$sessionOptions.UserName = "user"
$sessionOptions.Password = "password"

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Calculate previous weekday
$d = Get-Date
$d = $d.AddDays(-1)
if ($d.DayOfWeek -eq "Sunday")
{
    $d = $d.AddDays(-1)
}
if ($d.DayOfWeek -eq "Saturday")
{
    $d = $d.AddDays(-1)
}

$timestamp = $d.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

# Upload the file
$session.PutFiles("C:\source\path\prefix$timestamp.txt", "/remote/path/").Check()

# Disconnect, clean up
$session.Dispose()
```

---

See also:

- [Improve script to get previous week day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27481882/850848)
- [how to get previous working day in windows command (via powershell)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39990161/850848)

The second link shows, how to calculate the previous weekday for use in a batch file (although still using PowerShell), if you want to keep using batch file.